# Why 2 kinds of AppFabric?

Tags: azure, cloud, appfabric

I see that we now have both Windows Server AppFabric and Azure AppFabric.  Is this just a namespace collision in the Microsoft marketing department or do these technologies share common interfaces?  Someone told me that is was possible to run an application using Azure AppFabric on a local production server, then change the deployment target to Azure on demand.  Is this possible and consistent with Azure licensing? If so, can we use Windows Server AppFabric on the local server in this scenario?

I assume that data services would have to be maintained in the cloud for consistency, but moving the UI and business logic in and out of Azure would be a great way to cut down on hosting costs during periods of inactivity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is unfortunate that Microsoft have decided to refer to both of these things as a type of App Fabric.  AS Phil writes the Azure version is for the Azure Cloud and the Windows Server version is for your own machines.

Unfortunately the features between them are different and so you cannot simply move from one to the other.  I say unfortunate as we wanted to use a part of the Windows Server AppFabric, the distributed Cache (previously referred to as velocity, a much better name), on the cloud, and it is not available yet.

Comment: It's the Microsoft way - cool code name, rubbish product name! :-)

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that there is common ground between the teams, and that features are written for the Azure product first, then added to the Windows Server product.

The distinction between them is that Windows Server AppFabric is designed for internal company use, inside the firewall, whereas Azure AppFabric is the out and out cloud product.

Can you switch between them to just use the Azure piece in times of high load in the way you suggest? I don't *believe* so, but I'm happy to be corrected - the Azure side isn't something I've looked at in depth.